# Implementación de una estrategia. ¿Que hago mal en éste script?

Tags: pandas, python-3.7, jupyter

Como práctica en mi aprendizaje, intento implementar una estrategia de inversión basada en realizar una inversión inicial comprando un número determinado de acciones y, seguidamente, durante un período de tiempo, venderlas cuando el valor en la columna **position** cambia de 1 a 0 y comprar en caso contrario, invirtiendo el dinero obtenido en la venta anterior. He desarrollado este sript, pero estoy atascado ya que, al final, dependiendo de si en la columna **position** del último registro tengamos un 0 o un 1,  el script nos debería devolver uno de los dos valores, **strategy_number_of_stocks** ó **money_sale**. sin embargo, me devuelve 0 en ambas variables.
Agradeceré ayuda para poder avanzar en este ejercicio. Muestro a continuación el script en su fase de desarrollo actual.

```
# Consulta StackOverflow
import pandas as pd
from math import floor
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

# Importar cotizaciones
ticker = "GOOG"
start = "2020-1-2"
end = "2021-4-28"
nom_val = "GOOG"
df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
df.rename(columns={'High': 'high',  'Low': 'low', 'Open':'open', 
                      'Close':nom_val, 'Volume':'volume', 'Adj Close':'adj close'}, inplace=True)
df_valor = df[[nom_val]]

close_price = df_valor[nom_val]

position = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1] 

"""Creamos un df con la lista position"""
position = pd.DataFrame(position).rename(columns = {0:'macd_position'}).set_index(df_valor.index)

"""Creamos un único df  con las cotizaciones y la columna positión con valores 0 y 1."""
frames = [close_price, position]
strategy = pd.concat(frames, join = 'inner', axis = 1)

"""La estrategia simulada consiste en, vender cuando postion pasa de 1 a o y comprar en caso contrario"""

"""Al comprar acciones la primera vez, conseguimos valor_inversión / cotización_ese_día  acciones"""
"""Posteriormente, cuando vendemos conseguimos un dinero money_sale"""
"""Cuando volvemos a comprar conseguimos money_sale / cotización_ese_día de las acciones"""

investment_value = 100000

# Empzamos comprando aacciones con el invest_value
number_of_stocks = floor(investment_value/strategy[nom_val][0]) 
money_sale = 0

"""En la columna position de la primera fila [0] siempre tendremos un 1, ya que hemos realizado la inversión inicial"""

# definimos el nuevo df
# df = strategy.loc[:, [nom_val, 'stocks','money' ]] 
df = strategy.copy()


if strategy["macd_position"][0] == 1 :
    df["stocks"] = number_of_stocks  # número de acciones iniciales
    df["money"] = 0                 # dinero disponible inicialmente, posterior a la compra de acciones

# Aplicación de la estrategia    
for i in range(1, strategy.shape[0]):
    
    if df["macd_position"][i-1] ==   df["macd_position"][i]:               
        pass     
        
    elif df["macd_position"][i-1] == 1:
        # comprar
        df["stocks"] = df["money"][i-1]//df[nom_val][i]
        df["money"] = 0
        
    elif df["macd_position"][i-1] ==  0:
        # vender
        df["money"] = df["stocks"][i-1] * df[nom_val][i]      # vendo al precio del día actual  
        df["stocks"] = 0
        
df
```

Modifico el script, incoporando las recomendaciones de los comentarios y el resultado continúa siendo el mismo.

```
#...........................................
# Consulta StackOverflow
import pandas as pd
from math import floor
import pandas_datareader.data as pdr

# Importar cotizaciones
ticker = "GOOG"
start = "2020-1-2"
end = "2021-4-28"
nom_val = "GOOG"
df = pdr.DataReader(ticker, 'yahoo', start = start, end = end)
df.rename(columns={'High': 'high',  'Low': 'low', 'Open':'open', 
                      'Close':nom_val, 'Volume':'volume', 'Adj Close':'adj close'}, inplace=True)
df_valor = df[[nom_val]]

close_price = df_valor[nom_val]

position = [1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1,
       1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0,
       0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
       1, 0, 1] 

"""Creamos un df con la lista position"""
position = pd.DataFrame(position).rename(columns = {0:'macd_position'}).set_index(df_valor.index)

"""Creamos un único df  con las cotizaciones y la columna positión con valores 0 y 1."""
frames = [close_price, position]
strategy = pd.concat(frames, join = 'inner', axis = 1)

"""La estrategia simulada consiste en, vender cuando postion pasa de 1 a o y comprar en caso contrario"""

"""Al comprar acciones la primera vez, conseguimos valor_inversión / cotización_ese_día  acciones"""
"""Posteriormente, cuando vendemos conseguimos un dinero money_sale"""
"""Cuando volvemos a comprar conseguimos money_sale / cotización_ese_día de las acciones"""

investment_value = 100000

# Empzamos comprando aacciones con el invest_value
number_of_stocks = floor(investment_value/strategy[nom_val][0]) 
money_sale = 0

"""En la columna position de la primera fila [0] siempre tendremos un 1, ya que hemos realizado la inversión inicial"""

strategy["stocks"] =  0
strategy["money"] =  0  

if strategy["macd_position"][0] == 1 :
    strategy.iloc[0,2] = number_of_stocks  # número de acciones iniciales
    strategy.iloc[0,3] = 0                 # dinero disponible inicialmente, posterior a la compra de acciones

# Aplicación de la estrategia    
for i in range(1, strategy.shape[0]):
    
    if strategy["macd_position"][i-1] ==   strategy["macd_position"][i]:       
        #strategy.iloc[i,2] = strategy.iloc[i-1,2]
        #strategy.iloc[i,3] = strategy.iloc[i-1,3]        
        pass     
        
    elif strategy["macd_position"][i-1] == 1:
        # comprar
        strategy.iloc[i,2] = strategy.iloc[i-1,3]//strategy[nom_val][i]
        strategy.iloc[i,3] = 0
        
    elif strategy["macd_position"][i-1] ==  0:
        # vender
        strategy.iloc[i,3] = strategy.iloc[i-1,2] * strategy[nom_val][i]      # vendo al precio del día actual  
        strategy.iloc[i,2] = 0
        
strategy
```

[image: strategy]

[image: imágen]

Comment: No entiendo bien la estrategia, pero me da la sensación de que una vez que haya entrado por el primer `if` donde se pone `strategy_number_of_stocks` a cero, esa variable ya será cero siempre. No veo que en ningún otro lugar se incremente o cambie de valor, salvo en el tercer `if`, pero el valor que se le asigna será cero pues `money_sale` está inicializado con cero. Yo pondría `print()` en el cuerpo de cada `if` para imprimir los valores de esas dos variables y ver cómo van cambiando para descubrir el bug.

Comment: Para que se entienda mejor: pasar de 0 a 0 o de 1 a 1 implica mantener la inversión; pasar de 1 a 0 implica vender y pasar de 0 a 1, comprar. He puesto el" print" en las sentencias if y siempre me devuelve 0,0.

Comment: Es lo que supuse, pero entonces ¿no deberia haber un simple `pass` (no hacer nada) en esos casos en lugar de poner a 0 una variable?

Comment: Creo que no, por lo siguiente. Position[0] siempre es 1. Empezamos la estrategia en i= 1, y vemos como position pasa de 1 a 0, luego vendemos las acciones. En consecuencia aplica el último elif y, por lo tanto, pasamos a no tener acciones y si tener el dinero de la venta del número de acciones iniciales.

Comment: ¿Se te ocurre otro enfoque, pero en esta línea de compra y venta de acciones en momentos seleccionados previamente?. He visto otras estrategias basadas en rendimientos, pero yo quisiera desarrollar esta opción.

Comment: sigo sin verlo claro (me refiero a los dos primeros `if` dentro del bucle). Fijate que una asignación como `money_sale=money_sale` básicamente no hace nada, por lo que puedes eliminarla. Lo que queda entonces en esos `if` es una asignación a 0 de la otra variable, y eso es lo que no entiendo, pues los casos 0, 0 o 1,1 no deberían cambiar ninguna variable, si te entendí correctamente.

Comment: Efectivamente, es posible que sobren las dos primeras sentencias. Voy a asegurarme.

Comment: Lo que yo veo:

En el segundo elif, (comprar) la expresión 
strategy_number_of_stocks = floor(money_sale/strategy["macd_position"][i]) 
creo que debería ser 
strategy_number_of_stocks = floor(money_sale/strategy[nom_val][i]

Comment: Vaya, todo se reduce a evaluar si macd cruza arriba o abajo, para comprar/vender... creo que hay más variables de las necesarias, y más comprobaciones de las que debería.... Como el tema me gusta, voy a hacer un boceto de lo que yo haría, y te lo pongo como respuesta.

Comment: Efectivamente, hay que dividir el dinero que vamos a re-invertir entre el valor de la cotización ese día.

Comment: Los dos primeros if te los puedes ahorrar con una igualdad. Es decir 'if strategy["macd_position"][i-1] == strategy["macd_position"][i]' De este modo, da igual si los dos son 0 o los dos son 1, mantenemos posiciones.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Para empezar:**
Como crítica constructiva, hay varias cosas que debes mejorar en el script que estás programando. Algunas cosas las estás complicando demasiado y hay partes de tu código que son completamente ineficaces.
Por ejemplo:

.- Tienes dos variables que contienen la misma información `'ticker'` y `'nom_val'`.
.- Renombras las columnas, y en la siguiente sentencia eliminas todas excepto una.
.- Mantienes las fechas como índice del DataFrame (Esto parece ser el origen de uno de tus problemas, pues no puedes acceder por índices correctamente)
.- Es mucho más fácil calcular el valor de 'macd' y su cruce, que insertar una columna construida de forma manual, sobre todo si quieres que este código sea reusable para otros valores bursátiles, e incluso para otras fechas del mismo valor. Ese dato cambia según la cotización, y calcularlo es muy fácil.
.- El bloque `'if'` justo antes de inicar la aplicación de la estrategia no tiene ningún sentido. Lo lógico es empezar aplicando la estrategia desde la primera fila.
.- En el bucle `'for'` de aplicación de la estrategia usas `'shape'` para determinar el tamaño. Esto te devuelve filas y columnas, y solo necesitas saber el número de filas. Mejor usar `'len(df)'`
.- Finalmente el bucle de aplicación de la estrategia está bastante bien después de las modificaciones, pero si no te funciona debe haber algún error de acceso a los índices (aunque yo no lo veo)

Con todo eso, he preferido empezar de cero y crear el script limpio, y a mí me funciona. Paso a explicarte lo que he hecho:

**1.- Obtención de datos:**
He usado *yfinance* porque es gratis, rápido y simple para el tema que nos ocupa. Puedes ver la [documentación oficial](https://pypi.org/project/yfinance/) para aprender más, y consultar [yahoo finance](https://finance.yahoo.com/trending-tickers) para ver la lista de tickers disponibles, que es MUY extensa (Más de 250.000).
Con estas tres líneas, tienes un DataFrame con 2 columnas ('Date', 'Close') y un índice. Puedes poner cualquier ticker, yo he usado 'goog', para datos de cierre de un año atrás.

```
acción = yf.Ticker('goog')
df = pd.DataFrame(acción.history(period='1y')['Close'])
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)
```

**2.- Cálculo macd y señal:**
Dos líneas de código, añaden dos columnas al DataFrame con el macd y su señal, redondeados a 2 decimales.

```
df['macd'] = round(df['Close'].ewm(span=12).mean() - df['Close'].ewm(span=26).mean(),2)
df['signal'] = round(df['macd'].ewm(span=9, adjust=False).mean(),2)
```

**3.- Calculamos si macd es alcista o bajista, y acción a tomar:**
Añadimos dos columnas más para aplicar la estrategia. La primera está clara, nos sirve para determinar si macd está alcista (macd por encima de la señal) o bajista (macd por debajo), y en base a esta columna, añadimos otra que nos indica la acción a tomar. Esta puede tener 3 valores: (-1, 0 y 1). Lo que hace es tomar de la columna `'direction'` el valor de la fila actual, y restarle el valor de la fila anterior de la misma columna.
Así, si el valor anterior era 1 (alcista), y el de la fila actual es igual, la resta nos arroja '0', y la acción debe ser 'mantener'. El resto de combinaciones posibles son (0-0 = 0 'mantener'); (0-1 = -1 'vender'); y (1-0 = 1 'comprar')

```
df['direction'] = np.where((df['macd'] > df['signal']),1,0)
df['action'] = df['direction'].diff()
```

**4.- Aplicación de la estrategia:**
Y para terminar, creamos las dos columnas `'stocks'` y `'money'`, que rellenaremos con datos cuando apliquemos el bucle `'for'` siguiente. He mejorado un poco los cálculos para añadir la fracción de dinero que queda de resto al comprar acciones, que se va acumulando.

```
# añadimos dos columnas
df['stocks']    =  0
df['money']     =  100000

# aplicación de la estrategia
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df['action'][i-1] == 0:          # mantener
        df.loc[i,['stocks']] = df.loc[i-1,['stocks']]
        df.loc[i,['money']] = df.loc[i-1,['money']]
    elif df['action'][i-1] == 1:        # comprar
        df.at[i,['stocks']] = df.iloc[i-1,7]//df['Close'][i]
        df.at[i,['money']] = df.iloc[i-1,7]%df['Close'][i]
    elif df['action'][i-1] == -1:       # vender
        df.at[i,['money']] = df.iloc[i-1,7]+(df.iloc[i-1,6] * df['Close'][i])
        df.at[i,['stocks']] = 0
```

He preferido usar `'loc'` y `'at'` donde es posible, para usar etiquetas en vez de índices, pero esta es una decisión personal que me hace más legible el código. El uso que tú haces de `'iloc'` también es correcto.
Y el resultado final este:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime
import yfinance as yf

#obtenemos datos de cierre del ticker que nos interese:
acción = yf.Ticker('goog')
df = pd.DataFrame(acción.history(period='1y')['Close'])
df.reset_index(level=0, inplace=True)

# calculamos macd y señal
df['macd'] = round(df['Close'].ewm(span=12).mean() - df['Close'].ewm(span=26).mean(),2)
df['signal'] = round(df['macd'].ewm(span=9, adjust=False).mean(),2)

# calculamos dirección (alcista o bajista) del macd y acción a emprender
df['direction'] = np.where((df['macd'] > df['signal']),1,0)
df['action'] = df['direction'].diff()

# añadimos dos columnas
df['stocks']    =  0
df['money']     =  100000

# aplicación de la estrategia
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    if df['action'][i-1] == 0:          # mantener
        df.loc[i,['stocks']] = df.loc[i-1,['stocks']]
        df.loc[i,['money']] = df.loc[i-1,['money']]
    elif df['action'][i-1] == 1:        # comprar
        df.at[i,['stocks']] = df.iloc[i-1,7]//df['Close'][i]
        df.at[i,['money']] = df.iloc[i-1,7]%df['Close'][i]
    elif df['action'][i-1] == -1:       # vender
        df.at[i,['money']] = df.iloc[i-1,7]+(df.iloc[i-1,6] * df['Close'][i])
        df.at[i,['stocks']] = 0

print(df)
```

y la salida de datos (recortada) queda así:

```
         Date        Close   macd  signal  direction  action  stocks      money
0  2020-10-05  1486.020020   0.00    0.00          0     NaN     0.0  100000.00
1  2020-10-06  1453.439941  -0.73   -0.15          0     0.0     0.0  100000.00
2  2020-10-07  1460.290039  -0.72   -0.26          0     0.0     0.0  100000.00
3  2020-10-08  1485.930054   0.23   -0.16          1     1.0     0.0  100000.00
4  2020-10-09  1515.219971   1.91    0.25          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
5  2020-10-12  1569.150024   5.18    1.24          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
6  2020-10-13  1571.680054   7.31    2.45          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
7  2020-10-14  1568.079956   8.45    3.65          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
8  2020-10-15  1559.130005   8.66    4.65          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
9  2020-10-16  1573.010010   9.41    5.60          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
10 2020-10-19  1534.609985   7.76    6.04          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
11 2020-10-20  1555.930054   7.63    6.35          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
12 2020-10-21  1593.310059   9.53    6.99          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
13 2020-10-22  1615.329956  12.11    8.01          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
14 2020-10-23  1641.000000  15.43    9.50          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
15 2020-10-26  1590.449951  14.68   10.53          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
16 2020-10-27  1604.260010  14.79   11.38          1     0.0    65.0    1510.70
17 2020-10-28  1516.619995   9.16   10.94          0    -1.0    65.0    1510.70
18 2020-10-29  1567.239990   7.97   10.35          0     0.0     0.0  103381.30
19 2020-10-30  1621.010010  10.47   10.37          1     1.0     0.0  103381.30
20 2020-11-02  1626.030029  12.60   10.82          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
21 2020-11-03  1650.209961  15.72   11.80          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
22 2020-11-04  1749.130005  24.68   14.37          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
23 2020-11-05  1763.369995  32.32   17.96          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
24 2020-11-06  1761.750000  37.77   21.92          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
25 2020-11-09  1763.000000  41.66   25.87          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
26 2020-11-10  1740.390015  42.60   29.22          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
27 2020-11-11  1752.709961  43.72   32.12          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
28 2020-11-12  1749.839966  43.88   34.47          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
29 2020-11-13  1777.020020  45.46   36.67          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
30 2020-11-16  1781.380005  46.49   38.63          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
31 2020-11-17  1770.150024  45.94   40.09          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
32 2020-11-18  1746.780029  43.24   40.72          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
33 2020-11-19  1763.920044  41.91   40.96          1     0.0    63.0     941.41
34 2020-11-20  1742.189941  38.76   40.52          0    -1.0    63.0     941.41
35 2020-11-23  1734.859985  35.29   39.47          0     0.0     0.0  110237.59
36 2020-11-24  1768.880005  34.75   38.53          0     0.0     0.0  110237.59
37 2020-11-25  1771.430054  34.12   37.65          0     0.0     0.0  110237.59
```

Por último, algunas mejoras se pueden hacer; eliminar columnas que ya no se necesiten, redondear 'Close' a dos decimales, etc... pero eso ya son deberes para tí.

> Addendum:  Descargo de responsabilidad: Esta estrategia está bien como
> ejercicio de programación y aprendizaje, pero en ningún caso se
> recomienda su aplicación financiera real.

Comment: Jose LUis, gracias por tu esfuerzo y pedagogía. En mi autoproceso de apendizaje, estoy analizando diversos scripts de estrategias: RSI, ADX&RSI, Bollinger Bands, MACD, TSI&ROC%KST, Stochastic Oscillator & Moving Avergae, etc, intentando empaparme de diferentes formas de desarrollar estos algoritmos.

Comment: Muy bien. Es una forma divertida de poner en práctica lo aprendido, para mí también. Si he conseguido ayudarte, me doy por satisfecho. ;-)

Comment: Ahora lo veo claro. Yo quería pasar de una estrategia basada principalmente en listas, en otra con df. Mantener en el índice las fechas, es lo que me volvía loco. Resetear el índice ha sido fundamental. Desconocía la función "at". ¿ Es lo mismo "df.at[i,['stocks']]" que "df.at[i,'stocks']" ?

Comment: Si, es lo mismo. También se puede escribir 'df.loc[i].at['stocks']. Te recomiendo que revises la documentación oficial y veas los ejemplos. Una lectura 'entretenida', jejeje

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, procura realizar solo una respuesta en base a [answer]  o edita tu repuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Vamos a ello:

Damos por bueno que todo el código hasta `# Aplicación de la estrategia` está bien (no lo he comprobado) y vamos a lo que te da el problema.

Al empezar, y llegados a este punto del script, siempre estarás comprado y sin dinero. Así que hay que hacer 3 comprobaciones, que son:

```
if strategy["macd_position"][i-1] == strategy["macd_position"][i]: #macd no cruza; mantenemos y pasamos
    pass
elif strategy["macd_position"][i] == 1: #cruza hacia arriba, compramos
    n_acciones = dinero / precio
    dinero = 0
    print('Hemos comprado')
elif strategy["macd_position"][i] == 0: #cruza hacia abajo, vendemos
    dinero = n_acciones * precio
    n_acciones = 0  
    print('Hemos vendido')
```

Y con esto deberías resolverlo sin problemas. Básicamente, se resume en:

```
macd_actual = 1
macd_anterior = 1

if macd_anterior == macd_actual:    #macd no ha cruzado, mantenemos
    pass
elif macd_actual == 1:  #macd ha cruzado hacia arriba, compramos
    print('Hemos comprado')
elif macd_actual == 0:  #macd ha cruzado hacia abajo, vendemos
    print('Hemos vendido')
```

Si vas cambiando los valores de macd, verás que funciona.

Comment: Luis Niñomalo. Para comprobar el buen funcionamiento del script, incorpore en el mismo varias sentencias de creación de columnas, que me permitirán visualizar algunas variables. El script , incorporando tus comentarios, lo he incluido a continuación del de la consulta. A la vista está que, en el segundo loop, no carga adecuadamente los valores en las columnas stocks y money. Algo no va bien. ¿Qué falla?.

Comment: No sé como habrás implementado mi código en el tuyo, pero te aseguro que el mío funciona. Solo tienes que copiarlo y ejecutarlo. No obstante, te estoy preparando una respuesta más extensa y completamente funcional a tu otra pregunta. Te contesto por allí, y dejamos esta cerrada, que soluciona el tema de la pregunta original. Si te sirvió, no olvides aceptarla para dejarla cerrada.

Comment: Gracias por tu contribución, procura realizar solo una respuesta en base a [answer]  o edita tu repuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Teniendo en cuenta los comentarios anteriores, el script final es:

```
# Utilizando los precios de compra y venta.
df = strategy[[nom_val, "macd_position"]].copy(deep=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)

# añadimos dos columnas
df['stocks']    =  0
df['money']    =  0
df.at[0,["stocks"]] = 100000 // df.iloc[0,1]

# Aplicación de la estrategia
for i in range(1, len(df)):
    # Si pasamos de 1 a 0 vendemos
    if df["macd_position"][i-1] == 1 and df["macd_position"][i] == 0:           
        df.loc[i, ('money')] = df.loc[i-1, ('stocks')] * df.loc[i-1, (nom_val)]
        df.loc[i, ('stocks')] = 0
        
    # Si pasamos de 0 a 1 compramos
    elif df["macd_position"][i-1] == 0 and df["macd_position"][i] == 1 :        
        df.loc[i, ('stocks')] = df.loc[i-1, ('money')]//df.loc[i, (nom_val)]
        df.loc[i, ('money')] =  0
        
    # Si nos mantenemos en 0 o en 1
    else:        
        df.loc[i, ('money')] = df.loc[i-1, ('money')] 
        df.loc[i, ('stocks')] = df.loc[i-1, ('stocks')]

print(df )
```